# Getting the caller method name - Reflection and CallerInfo attribute

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.5, callermembername

Just bench-marked the performance of using `StackTrace` and `CallerInfo Attributes`.

Shockingly I found that using `StackTrace` is much faster though every where I read that `To get the caller method name, the preferred approach is CallerInfo attributes`.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Method1();  
        }

         static void Method1([CallerMemberName]string memberName = "")
         {
            double stackTraceTimings = 0;
            var sw = new Stopwatch();

            foreach(var item in Enumerable.Range(1,1000).ToList())
            {
               sw.Start();
               var callerName = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
               sw.Stop();
               stackTraceTimings += sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time for retrieving the caller name using StackFrame in 1000 iterations ={0}",stackTraceTimings/1000);

            stackTraceTimings = 0;
            foreach(var item in Enumerable.Range(1,1000).ToList())
            {
                sw.Start();
                var callerName = (memberName);
                sw.Stop();
                stackTraceTimings += sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time for retrieving the caller name using callerInfo Attribute in 1000 iterations ={0}",stackTraceTimings/1000);
        }
```

***OUTPUT:
Elapsed Time for retrieving the caller name using StackFrame in 1000 iterations =9.48074760000001***

***Elapsed Time for retrieving the caller name using callerInfo Attribute in 1000 iterations =21.7074064***

Did I misunderstood anything ? Using `CallerInfo` attributes is the preferred approach right ?

Thanks to the below answer for pointing out.

I have to re-start the timer every time in the loop.

So, who wins ? As the below answer says, `CallerInfo`. Because, it is a compile-time feature and is faster.

***Elapsed Time for retrieving the caller name using StackFrame in 1000 iterations =0.00762619999999992***

***Elapsed Time for retrieving the caller name using callerInfo Attribute in 1000 iterations =0.00639420000000002***

I used the below code (revised) and got the above results.

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Method1();  
        }

         static void Method1([CallerMemberName]string memberName = "")
         {
            double stackTraceTimings = 0;
            var sw = new Stopwatch();

            foreach(var item in Enumerable.Range(1,1000).ToList())
            {
               sw.Start();
               var callerName = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
               sw.Stop();
               Console.Write(callerName);
               sw.Restart();
               stackTraceTimings += sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time for retrieving the caller name using StackFrame in 1000 iterations ={0}",stackTraceTimings/1000);


            stackTraceTimings = 0;
            foreach(var item in Enumerable.Range(1,1000).ToList())
            {
                sw.Start();
                var callerName = (memberName);
                Console.Write(callerName);
                sw.Stop();
                sw.Restart();

                stackTraceTimings += sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time for retrieving the caller name using callerInfo Attribute in 1000 iterations ={0}",stackTraceTimings/1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling the CallerMemberNameAttribute "callerInfo"?  Confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset timer before second loop. `sw.Start` starts `Stopwatch` from state it was after first loop, so second result is actually time for both StackTrace and Attribute-based solutions summed together.

`CallerMethodName` is compile-type feature, it should definitely be faster.

With fixed code timing for `CallerMethodName` from your results is:

21.7074064 - (9.48074760000001 * 2) = **2.7459111999999806**

That's much faster, isn't it?

*subtracted first time twice: once for lack of `Reset` call and once for `+=` instead of `=`.*

**Update**

These results seems to be much too big. **Are you sure you're using Release build, run from outside Visual Studio?** I think not, because otherwise you'd get exact same results for both: `callerName` is never used and will probably be optimized to no-op (at least for second case).

Comment: Yup, you are right. Thanks for pointing. I will update the post. :)

Comment: Oh! I am using a online compiler. Not Visual studio because for the moment I don't use one.

Comment: I printed the methodNames to prevent `callerName is never used and will probably be optimized to no-op (at least for second case).` and put the updated results